# How to terminate sourcing of "parent" script?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

Suppose one *sources* the script `A.sh`, which in turn *sources* a second script, `B.sh`.

Is there anything that can `B.sh` can do to cause the sourcing of of `A.sh`<sup>1</sup> to terminate, short of exiting the sourcing shell altogether?

---

**IMPORTANT:** Here I'm assuming *no cooperation at all* from `A.sh`.  IOW, assume that `A.sh` is completely agnostic about what `B.sh` may do.

---

Of course, if `B.sh` runs `return`, the sourcing of `B.sh` will terminate, but not the sourcing of `A.sh`.  On the other hand, if `B.sh` runs `exit`, not only `A.sh` will terminate, but also its parent shell.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I take it as a given that terminating the sourcing of `A.sh` would automatically cause the sourcing of `B.sh` to terminate as well.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.</sup>

Comment: I don't think this is possible without the cooperation of the script that sources `A.sh`.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks!  I'd be happy to accept your comment as the answer to my question.